# SQL Server datetime2 parse issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

When I run the following SQL at my local SQL Server instance:

```
DECLARE @t DATETIME2 = '2019-12-12 00:00:00'
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to convert @t to a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter object. The specified literal cannot be converted to DateTime2(System.Data.SqlDbType), as it used an unsupported date/time format. Use one of the supported date/time formats. Literal value: 2019-12-12 00:00:00

The only way to fix it is to add 'T' between date and time

```
DECLARE @t DATETIME2 = '2019-12-12T00:00:00'
```

At the same time, this script runs perfectly fine at my production server (without adding 'T').

I tried to find the difference and don't see anything that could affect the behavior:

- Collation is the same at both servers - `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
- Language is the same - *English (United States)*
- Server version: LOCAL is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition (64-bit) v14.0.2027 RTM; REMOTE is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) v14.0.1000 RTM
- Host OS: LOCAL is Windows 10 Pro; REMOTE is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Can somebody explain, why I'm getting the error locally?

Comment: How do you execute that query ? From the error message, it looks like you have a front end application that execute it. Please include that in your question

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on Win10/SQL Server 2017 locally in SSMS - works just fine. I agree with @Squirrel: seem like your not executing this in SSMS, but from some app - maybe there's something in that app that causes this problem. SQL Server on its own should be just fine

Comment: @Squirrel I was running it in SSMS. The reason and solution is found, thanks to Dan Guzman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a client-side error so it seems you are running the query from SSMS with the Enable Always Encrypted (column encryption) option for the connection (connection Options-->Always Encrypted) on the remote client but not the prod server. With the option enabled, the SSMS client parses literals in order to build parameters for AE.

Unlike `'2019-12-12 00:00:00'`, the [ISO 8601 datetime format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) literal `'2019-12-12T00:00:00'` is unambiguous and can be reliably parsed regardless of the client regional settings.

So your options are to either use an ISO 8601 datetime format or turn of the SSMS Enable AE option for the connection.